# Delete from subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

I am using Hibernate in my application. Currently I am trying to execute the following query:

```
DELETE FROM ActiveTimes a WHERE
a.begin>=:from AND a.begin<=:to
AND a.end>=:from AND a.end<=:to
    AND a in( 
         SELECT al FROM ActiveTimes al 
             JOIN al.source.stage st
         JOIN st.level.dataSource ds
     WHERE ds=:dataSource)
```

But I get an error: `Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous`.
This feels normal, because the created SQL query looks like this:

```
delete 
from
    active_times 
where
    begin>=? 
    and begin<=? 
    and end>=? 
    and end<=? 
    and (
        id in (
            select
                id 
            from
                active_times activeti1_ 
            inner join
                sources sourc2_ 
                    on activeti1_.source=sourc2_.id 
            inner join
                stage stage3_ 
                    on sourc2_.id=stage3_.source 
            inner join
                levels levels4_ 
                    on stage3_.level=levels4_.id 
            inner join
                datasources datasource5_ 
                    on levels4_.data_source=datasource5_.id 
            where
                id=?
        )
    )
```

If I change the query to:

```
DELETE FROM ActiveTimes a WHERE
a.begin>=:from AND a.begin<=:to
AND a.end>=:from AND a.end<=:to
    AND a.id in( 
         SELECT al.id FROM ActiveTimes al 
             JOIN al.source.stage st
         JOIN st.level.dataSource ds
     WHERE ds.id=:dataSource)
```

I get another error: `You can't specify target table 'active_times' for update in FROM clause`.

I am not very experimented with JPQL(or HQL) so I do not understand why the query looks like that in the first example.

The new error occurs because apparently I cannot make a subquery on the delete table in MySQL.

Do you have any suggestions on how can I rewrite one of the above queries in order to make it work?

Comment: This is one of the (many) stupid limitations of MySQL. You need to re-write the sub-select into a join.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can you please elaborate on this idea? What is more, can you please tell me why the first version of the query got translated in such an ambiguous manner? Thank you!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name An answer has been posted. Is that how the JPQL query should look like?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use JPQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the sub-query.  It's unnecessary.  I'm not sure how to write SQL code in Hybernate, but I'm guessing it would be something like this:

```
DELETE a 

FROM   ActiveTimes a

       JOIN a.source.stage st
       JOIN st.level.dataSource ds

WHERE  a.begin>=:from AND a.begin<=:to
       AND a.end>=:from AND a.end<=:to
       AND ds.id=:dataSource;
```

Comment: If I do it as you suggest, I get this error: `unexpected token: FROM near line 1, column 10`.

Comment: remove `a` after `DELETE`, syntax is `delete from ...`

Comment: Thanks bellabax.  Would it know to just delete from the ActiveTimes table?  In MySQL you include the alias so it knows which table to delete from if you have multiple tables in your FROM clause.